# Pass wildcard array to cp

Tags: linux, cp

I need help with passing a wild card array to cp, I know it can be done but cant figure it out,

ive got 3 files all start with the word somefile but have 3 different extensions

- somefile.conf
- somefile.dat
- somefile.py

there in a folder with a bunch of other files and I just want to copy them to a different location.

I remember is being something like

`cp somefile.[py conf dat] /somewhere`

but this isn't working

Ive searched the net and can't find it with the keywords i'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the shell, you could use **brace expansion**

```
cp somefile.{py,conf,dat} /somewhere
```

Comment: That done the trick thankyou very much, will accept when su lets me